# Sum of binomial coefficients weighted by 1/t

Tags: statistics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

I would like to evaluate the following sum in terms of $n$. The sum is essentially a weighted sum of a binomial distribution with N = 2n and p = $\frac{1}{n}$. I can't figure out how to do it, despite looking through a lot of posts on here and a few papers. Could anyone help?

$$\sum_{t=1}^{2n} {2n\choose{t}} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^t \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{2n-t} \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Well this is the key insight for your solution

$$
(1+x)^{2n}=\sum_{r=0}^{2n}{2n\choose r}x^r\\
{(1+x)^{2n}-1\over x}=\sum_{r=1}^{2n}{2n\choose r}x^{r-1}
$$

Now we can integrate on both sides from 0 to $1\over n-1$

$$
I=\sum^{2n}_{r=1}{2n\choose r}{1\over r(n-1)^r}
$$

Where $$I=\int_0^{1\over n-1}{(1+x)^{2n}-1\over x}dx$$
Now multiply $({n\over n-1})^{2n}$ on both sides to get

$$
\sum_{r=1}^{2n}{2n \choose r}{1\over r}({1\over n})^r({n\over n-1})^{2n-r}=\left({n\over n-1}\right)^{2n}I
$$

Closed form of the integral if anyone cares
$$
I=2(_3F_2(1,1,1-2n;2,2;-{1\over n}))
$$
Where F is the generalised hypergeometric function

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by substituting $t$? What do I substitute $t$ for? Also, this is giving me a fraction over $r+1$, when I need a fraction over $r$ (to match the $r$ in $n$ choose $r$).

Comment: Posted the full answer in edit @c12345 make sense?

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it!! However, when I graph the two functions (your derivation and the original) to compare, the graphs don't look the same, which seems to suggest they're not equal. I think I'm also not understanding how you got $\sum_{r=0}^{2n} {2n \choose{r}}\frac{t^{r+1}}{r+1} = \sum_{r=1}^{2n+1} \frac{t^r}{r}$ -- should it be $\sum_{r=0}^{2n} {2n \choose{r}}\frac{t^{r+1}}{r+1} = \sum_{r=1}^{2n+1} {2n \choose{r-1}}\frac{t^r}{r}$, and, if so, how do you have ${2n \choose{r}}$ in the summation in the following line?

Comment: Ye one sec there is a big blunder gimme a couple min I'll see if I can fix it @c12345

Comment: This one i checked with desmos seems to be working the closed form of the integral is hypergeometric so fun ig